# Java Cannot make xml from bytes

Tags: java, xml

I have to make xml document on client side, convert it to byte array and do the reverse sequence on server side.

My xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<dirStruct>
<file modified="1398855221782" name="sharedFolder\hey.txt"/>
</dirStruct>
```

... verified with online xml validators, no errors found.

Get it on server side:

```
byte[] msg = new byte[5000]; // buffer is large enough, so it isn't problem.
in.read(msg);
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(msg)); // Here's i get an exeption
```

... input data isn't null, verified up.

Exception is:

```
[Fatal Error] :1:138: Content is not allowed in trailing section.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 138; Content is not allowed in trailing section.
```

Where's im wrong?

====================================

Client side:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
Element root = doc.createElement("dirStruct");
doc.appendChild(root);

Element node = doc.createElement("file");
node.setAttribute("name", file.toString());
node.setAttribute("modified", Long.toString(file.lastModified()));
root.appendChild(node);

TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(stream);
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

... stream is `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

If i will change `stream` to `System.out`, i will get correct result too.

To byte array is just `data = stream.toByteArray();`

Comment: What do you get if you make a String from the bytes and print it?

Comment: @EvanKnowles, absolute copy of client's version.

Comment: And if you feed the original directly into the builder it works?

Comment: Yes it does. Have no idea why it doesn't on server side..

Comment: I think you've already answered your own question. The code isn't the problem, but rather the data sent from client to server. Your question does not explain how the data is sent/received.

Comment: @Martin, sended 203 bytes, received 203 too :( wtf

Comment: It sounds like there're some characters (whitespace perhaps) being inserted. How are you converting from String to byte[] originally?

Comment: @EvanKnowles, please check post's update. Also seems you are right about whitespaces.

Comment: Could it be an encoding issue? Is the original file created in a Windows machine and sent to a Linux one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The buffer is too large. You are getting real content after `</dirStruct>` as char 0x000000.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<dirStruct>
<file modified="1398855221782" name="sharedFolder\hey.txt"/>
</dirStruct>¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶
¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶
¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶
¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶
```

is 141 bytes, there are at least 4859 bytes of 0x00000000.